# Right Align part of a Chunk with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I´m new to iTextSharp and I´m trying to create a PDF.
Just a simple example. If I do something like this:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();

p.Add(new Chunk("789456|Test", f5));
newDocument.Add(p);
p.Add(new Chunk("456|Test", f5));
newDocument.Add(p);
p.Add(new Chunk("12345|Test", f5));
newDocument.Add(p);
```

I get this result:

```
789456|Test
456|Test
12345|Test
```

What can I do to right align part of the text in my chunk. Like this:

```
789456|Test
   456|Test
 12345|Test
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please take a look at the following examples: [chapter 4](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C04). They introduce the concept of a `PdfPTable`. Instead of creating `Chunk` objects like this `"789456|Test"`, and then do the impossible to have the separate parts of the content of these `Chunk`s align correctly, you'll discover that it's much easier to create a simple `PdfPTable` with 2 columns, adding `"789456|"` and `"Test"` as content of borderless cells. All other workarounds will inevitably lead to code that is more complex and error-prone.

The answer provided by Karl Anderson is much more complex; the answer provided by Manish Sharma is wrong. Although I don't know C#, I've tried to write an example (based on how I would achieve this in Java):

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.DefaultCell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
table.DefaultCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
table.addCell(new Phrase("789456|", f5));
table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
table.addCell(new Phrase("Test", f5));
table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
table.addCell(new Phrase("456|", f5));
table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
table.addCell(new Phrase("Test", f5));
table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
table.addCell(new Phrase("12345|", f5));
table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
table.addCell(new Phrase("Test", f5));
doc.Add(table);
```

Note that the default width of a table is 80% of the available width (the horizontal space between the margins) and that the table is center aligned by default. You may want to change these defaults using [`WidthPercentage`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter04/ColumnWidths.cs) and [`HorizontalAlignment`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter04/TableAlignment.cs)

Comment: I thought that there was an easy way to do that using chunks and paragraphes, but I guess there isn´t. This solution you proposed worked for me. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: table.DefaultCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT? Does this make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can only apply the alignment to the `Paragraph` object and not the `Chunk`s, so you will need to use a page layout using columns.

Read [iTextSharp - Page Layout with Columns](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/89/iTextSharp-Page-Layout-with-Columns) for details on getting layout closer to what you are asking for.

Comment: I think your solution is overkill for what is actually asked. I'll provide another answer.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie - Fair enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @KarlAnderson.
I agree with BrunoLowagie. Using tables is easier and accomplishes what I need.

Answer (score -1):

try this,
this is sample code for you.

```
private void CreatePdf()
{
        using (FileStream msReport = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {
            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 20, 10);

            PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, msReport);
            doc.Open();

            PdfPTable pt = new PdfPTable(1);
            PdfPCell _cell;

            _cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("789456|Test"));
            _cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            _cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            _cell.Border = 0;
            pt.AddCell(_cell);

            _cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("456|Test"));
            _cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            _cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            _cell.Border = 0;
            pt.AddCell(_cell);
            _cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("12345|Test"));
            _cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            _cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            _cell.Border = 0;
            pt.AddCell(_cell);

            doc.Open();
            doc.Add(pt);
            doc.Close();
      }
}
```

Comment: This won't work, not even is you change the `HorizontalAlignment` to `ALIGN_CENTER`. You realle need a table with two columns `new PdfPTable(2)` and you need to create two cells for each row: `new PdfPCell(new Phrase("789456|"))` and `new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Test"));` The code could also be simplified by using a default cell without creating the `PdfPCell` objects explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Manish Sharma, but using just one cell right aligned won´t work for what I need. Only if all the "Test" are equal.