# How to do right justification for PDF creating through Itextsharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I am generating Pdf through itextSharp. Sample code is given below.In this case Below Salary and Hike values are coming as left justified but i want these fields as right justified. As i am giving the same X cordinates 240, 280 for the values too.How can I do right justification.

```
            cb.BeginText();
            writeText(cb, "Salary", 240, 395, f_cb, 8);
            writeText(cb, "Hike ", 280, 395, f_cb, 8);
            writeText(cb, drOtherObj["Salary"].ToString(), 240, 335, f_cb, 8);
            writeText(cb, drOtherObj["Hike"].ToString(), 280, 335, f_cb, 8);
            cb.EndText();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088097/right-align-part-of-a-chunk-with-itextsharp

Comment: Essentially you chose to do everything manually by using immediate content byte operations. Thus, you have to calculate the width of string and therefrom derive the starting position on your own. Alternatively switch to a solution as pointed to by @MihaiHantea.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are writing manual PDF commands instead of using the abstractions that iTextSharp provides?